# Need help making a popup window based on array

Tags: php, arrays, html, calendar

I need help making an onscreen popup window that opens a different picture/image based on the variables/date. Is this possible? Help, please.

```
$calendarday = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24");

$dat = date("d");

foreach ($calendarday as $day) {

if ($day <= $dat) {

    echo '<a href="' . $day . '.jpg"><img src="' . $day . '.png" alt="' . $day . '"></a>';

} else {

    echo '<a href="juks.png"><img src="' . $day . '.png" alt="' . $day . '"></a>';

    }
}
```

This is for a Christmas calendar.

Answer (score 0):

There are some } to much and also a mistake in echo. Also you have to put the format in date() into ""

```
$calendarday = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24");
$dat = date("d");

foreach ($calendarday as $day) {
    if ($day <= $dat) {
        echo '<a href="' . $day . '.jpg"><img src="' . $day . '.png" alt="' . $day . '"></a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="juks.png"><img src="' . $day . '.png" alt="' . $day . '"></a>';
    }
}
```